# Add new UIButton "state" with custom image

Tags: ios, inheritance, uibutton

I'm trying to build a simple peg jumping game (see: http://cl.ly/2x0v1V3z351t0j3d3y0L).

My plan is to make each "peg" a UIButton and toggle the UIButton states for the different images that need to be displayed at different times during the game. Using the default states for UIButton gets me pretty far but I need to add one extra state beyond the default 4.

How would I go about doing this? I figure I will need to sub class UIButton to create a custom UIButton object but this is where I get stuck. I can't find any resources on adding new button states. Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link below was a major help to me implementing my own custom button.  I basically took that guy's code and made it ARC compatible, but the basic principle in what he's done really works great!

[Custom Button States](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/2010/09/22/custom-uibuttons-via-subclassing/)

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIBUtton` and add a custom state variable, then use the setter to change the image that is shown.

Comment: You cannot easily subclass UIButton.